# « Être loin de compte » vs. « Être loin du compte »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Je sais que l'expression **être loin *du* compte** signifie *se tromper*. Mais selon le *TLF*, cette expression a deux versions :

> [Être loin de compte*, loin du compte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/loin).

Et selon *Larousse*, elle n'a qu'une version :

> [*Être loin du compte*, se tromper de beaucoup sur l'évaluation d'une
>   quantité ; être éloigné de la vérité](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/compte/17808/locution).

Pourquoi est-ce que le *TLF* a cette expression en deux versions différentes ? Ce sont de raisons stylistiques, sémantiques ou bien étymologiques que ce dictionnaire nous la donne en deux versions distinctes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La réponse est sur le site du CNRTL, en bas de page ! 
Il est précisé que "loin de" est vieilli !

Une recherche ngram rapide corrobore cette idée :
[image: recherche ngram]

La forme exacte est actuellement *loin du compte*, mais le dictionnaire a préféré donner la version désuète, pour référence future je suppose !

Comment: Le _ngram_ est assez clair, mais pouvez-vous svp. m'indiquer où au bas de la page de quoi (l'entrée à _loin_ ou à _compte_) est-il indiqué que « loin de compte » est vieilli, et pourquoi dites vous uniquement « loin de » entre guillemets. Je trouve _loin de compte_ dans [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/Compte), même si personnellement je ne l'ai jamais vu. Merci !